# DLL being marked as DELETEPENDING

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, dll

I have a problem running an application on one of my Windows boxes. I cannot replicate it on other similar Windows boxes, and it has only just started occurring. Here's the situation:

1. Using Visual Studio, I can build an application that I have written. It builds one executable: Application.exe, and I can see in its bin/Debug directory, this executable and all of the DLLs that I know the application depends on, including Microsoft.Windows.Azure.Configuration.dll.
2. When I run the application, the application stops running, and when I come to investigate the problem, I can see that the Microsoft.Windows.Azure.Configuration.dll has been renamed to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration.dll.5502888.DeletePending.5502888.DeletePending.5502904.DeletePending.5502919.DeletePending.5502935.DeletePending.5502950.DeletePending

I have never seen this behavior before, though I have been running the same application for a year or so on this machine. Does anyone know what might happening?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Disable your anti-malware and try again.

Comment: Hmm - interesting - I'll be embarrassed if this is the correct answer! I cannot seen anti-malware running on this box (either in the taskbar notification area or in the list of processes that I can identify). I'm also fairly confident that this box has not been re-configured recently, but I will check now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I assume you've tried rebooting? :-)

Comment: Yes - no change in behavior sadly.

Comment: I was faced with similar issue (but another Microsoft dll). Did you figure out what is going on there?

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't seen this myself, I know that Windows supports pending deletes (as tracked in the [FILE_OBJECT structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545834(v=vs.85).aspx)) if you open the file with the [right permissions](https://boostgsoc13.github.io/boost.afio/doc/html/afio/FAQ/deleting_open_files.html).

Loking around the Internet, I see that others have hit this issues with [Windows Defender](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/delete-pending-caused-by-mpengine-dll-breaks-processing-of-batch-f.4024736/) and others have commented on many other AV software doing similar things.  Given that it appears to be a feature of the Windows API, though, any application could cause it.

It looks like debugging with ProcMon from Sysinternals might be the best way to track down what is actually holding the file open.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little embarrassing. I believe that I did solve my problem, but unfortunately, can no longer remember what I did. If memory serves me though, I think that the problem lay with log4net, and something it was doing. I will try to dredge my memory for more information.

Comment: Yes, in my case log4net was involved too. Custom file appender was trying to remove old log files, and incorrectly started to delete DLLs which were placed in the same directory.